# UUID as primary key in sailsjs domain

Tags: sails.js

I am using Sails.js version 1.0.2. I am trying to assign uuid as primary key throughout the application.  I tried putting
`id: { type: 'string', defaultsTo:uuid.v4() }` in model.js but it's saying Primary keys must be unique therefore can't contain a default value.

_________________EDIT_______________

I tried this code in my domain

```
beforeCreate: function (modelObj, next) {
modelObj.id = uuidv4.v4();
next();
}
```

And edit my Model.js configuration is like :

```
attributes: {
createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
id: { type: 'string',required:true},
}
```

beforeCreate method never executes and throw the error while creating the record like:

```
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response: 
{ UsageError: Invalid new record.
Details:
Missing value for required attribute `id`.  Expected a string, but 
instead, got: undefined
```

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this instead of giving default value

```
beforeCreate: function (modelObj, next) {
    modelObj.id = uuid.v4();
    next();
  }
```

You can add this piece of function in your model. This gets invoked whenever there is a create operation on model.

Your **Model.js** should looks something like this

```
attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    id: { type: 'string',required:true},
},
beforeCreate: function (modelObj, next) {
    modelObj.id = uuid.v4();
    next();
}
```

Sample code of my Controller and Model,

**TestController.js**

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res) {
        Test.create({"name": "arshad"})
            .then(function(result){
                res.send("done");
            })
    }
};
```

**Test.js** Model

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
     id: { type: 'string', required: true },
     name: { type: 'string' }
  },
  beforeCreate: function(obj, next) {
     obj.id = 'someId';
     next();
  }
};
```

This is how your model and controller will look like. This will add **someId** as defined in beforeCreate function to the object

In your case you are using uuid package. Check in debugging mode whether uuid reference is available in beforeCreate or not

Comment: I edited my question. Can you please see if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: check my updated answer. also post your whole model code

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can reproduce it using sails new testApp with web option. It will create a User Model and I was trying to change it.

Comment: check the updated answer, sample controller and model code added